# Show php variable value in confirmation box in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have following code i want to show name that is the result of the query.

```
function lead_delete(del_id)
{
    <?php
    $lead_name = mysql_query("select lead_name from business_lead where id=" .
            $del_id) Or die(mysql_error());

    while ($nt_lead_name = mysql_fetch_array($lead_name)) {
        $crm_lead_name = $nt_lead_status['lead_name'];
    }
    ?>
    var name=<?php $crm_lead_name; ?>;

    var confirmation;
    var confirmation=confirm("You Really want to Detele Leader "+name );


}   

</script>
```

how can i print the name that get from above query...

Comment: what query? where do you want to show it?

Comment: This isn't possible. PHP is parsed *before* javascript, meaning you cannot pass javascript variables to PHP without something like AJAX, or supplying the value in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

If `del_id` is php variable then it should be `$del_id` instead of `del_id`

```
var confirmation=confirm("You Really want to Detele Leader "+ <?php echo $del_id;?>);
```

As you passing `del_id` as a function parameter then no need to use php . you can easily get variable like below

```
var confirmation=confirm("You Really want to Detele Leader " + del_id);
```

As per updated question:-

```
var name=<?php $crm_lead_name;?>;
```

it should be

```
var name= '<?php echo $crm_lead_name;?>';
```

And also you want pass `del_id` lead_delete() function on click event then you have to use AJAX here.

For your reference

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: before that call above function 'onclick' in anchor tag that delid i want use in following query. i have a query<?php 
   $lead_name=mysql_query("select lead_name from business_lead where id=".del_id)Or die(mysql_error());
   while($nt_lead_name=mysql_fetch_array($lead_name))
   {
    $crm_lead_name=$nt_lead_status['lead_name'];
   }
   
  ?> because i want to show name that get by the above query and that name i want show in condirmation box

Comment: Where you defined $del_id? please show your complete block of code

Comment: see <a href="index.php?del_id='.$del_id.'" id="delete" onClick=" return lead_delete('.$del_id.');">Delete</a> i pass the del_id <script type="text/javascript">

function lead_delete(del_id)
{
<?php $lead_name=mysql_query("select lead_name from business_lead where id=".$del_id)Or die(mysql_error());  while($nt_lead_name=mysql_fetch_array($lead_name))
{
$crm_lead_name=$nt_lead_status['lead_name'];
}
?>
var name=<?php $crm_lead_name;?>;
var confirmation;
var confirmation=confirm("You Really want to Detele Leader "+ name);    
if(confirmation==true)
{
return true;
}
} 
</script>

Comment: You can't pass `$del_id` php variable inside php query like this way. That's why AJAX comes into  existence ?

Comment: so how can i use to use del_id in php select query

Comment: See your all script inside index.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<?php echo $del_id;?>` tag in this function (because you may change del_id when call function), but you can create del_id on your page, if you have `$del_id` php value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var del_id = <?php echo $del_id;?>;
function lead_delete(del_id) {
  var confirmation;
  var confirmation=confirm("You Really want to Detele Leader " + del_id);

  if(confirmation==true)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```